# Centering textview in linearlayout at runtime

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I'm trying to inflate at runtime some textviews into a linearlayout. This the xml layout (the textviews are just dummies):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/show_textContainer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="10:20"
        android:textAppearance="@style/hugeText"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="10:15"
        android:textAppearance="@style/mediumText"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="10:10"
        android:textAppearance="@style/mediumText"
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

and this is the rendering from Android Studio:

[Rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DU8Gy.png)

At runtime I create custom TextViews (named DynamicTextView) with my custom style:

```
public class DynamicTextView extends TextView {
   public DynamicTextView(Context context) {
      super(context, null, R.style.largeText);
   }
}
```

(R.style.largeText is

```
<style name="largeText">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
</style>
```

)

The custom text view added at runtime have also some custom textAppearance (the same of the dummies):

```
<style name="mediumText">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/mediumTextDimen</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/alarmBlueMedium</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>

</style>
```

You would expect both dummies and runtime textviews to be aligned in the same way, but, surprise surprise, they don't:

[Runtime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPnFz.png)

What's going on under the hood that I cannot understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your textview's `layout_width` from `fill_parent` to `wrap_content`

code snippet

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

Comment: okay, don't know why but I really expected that match_parent(/fill_parent) would be necessary to center an element. Thank you!